# Openshift pre_start hook does not work on app restart

Tags: java, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have set up an OpenShift testing app using tomcat6 (jbossews-1.0) cartridge, a pre_start action hook with name pre_start_jbossews-1.0 was pushed to the remote repository. The hook includes a JVM export statement that runs a javaagent like below:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:<...javagent jar location...>"
```

This actually worked fine when the app was started using

`rhc app start <app name>`

I could see in the rhc tail which showed something like

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -javaagent:...
```

However, when I used app restart

```
rhc app restart <app name>
```

The jvm opts was no longer picked up and the javaagent did not seem to be running anymore

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are separate hooks for the 'restart' event. You probably need to duplicate your insertion in 'pre_restart'.